# What are the tasks of a Quality Assurance track in a software procurement, implementation and upgrade project

Tags: project-team, quality, quality-management, procurement

An organization (bank) is procuring a software from a foreign company and at the same time they are also taking a major upgrade for another software (core banking system). A team has been formed as a Project Management Office to operate this project with different tracks like lending, forex, general banking, MIS and Quality Assurance (QA).

In the above scenario, **in a software procurement, implementation and upgrade project**, what would be the jobs, tasks, duties and the job description that the QA track should have?

Comment: Homework question?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to the PMBOK-Guide, QA has to plan, manage and controll quality throughout the project. So QA will have to identify all standards and requirements and plan how they can be met. This can only be successful when it happens hand in glove with the other teams.
Same goes with quality management while the project is worked on. QA has to make sure that the quality management plan and the processes are followed. And the finished deliverables have to be controlled. So if this actually has to be a separate team (I prefer multidisciplinary  teams), make sure that it works deeply embedded into the other teams.